# Presto millis ovewflow

Tags: presto, trino

I've a table in cassandra with a date column
I'm trying to query the table in presto:

`select max(date) from table`

But I'm getting the following error:

`SQL Error [65536]: Query failed (#20230622_092934_00095_4jhi3): Millis overflow: 8862879502347000`

How can I filter out the record with the 'strange' date?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I've tried with several versions, from 344 to the latest version

Comment: That seems like a bug in the Cassandra connector. The connector is probably not handling the conversion from the underlying value properly. Can you file a bug report under http://github.com/trinodb/trino? Please include the full stacktrace for that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with filter out the problematic date by specifying a range in the query and adjust the date range based on your requirement.

Example:

select Max(date)
FROM table
WHERE date>= '1900-01-01' AND date<= '2023-06-22';

Comment: the same error. Presto cannot filter by date because it is not recognizing the date